# Regular expression for separate lat and long

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with two regular expressions, one for latitude value, -85.05112878 < lat < 85.05112878, and one for longitude value, -180.0 < long < 180.0

help is much appreciated

Comment: regex can't reasonably help validate the range of such numbers... You'd be better to use regex to locate the lat/long, and then validate the value's range in software... remember, regex is character-based, not numeric...

Comment: if you gave us an example of your input, and what language you're using, we could suggest a suitable way to do this

Comment: Firstly, SO is not a code service, please show your efforts so far and an MVCE

Comment: Also, Attie is (mostly) correct, range bounding is a task that regex is not the proper tool for. Regular expressions can be used for range bounding in the same way that a hammer can be used to drive a screw into a plank.

Comment: Will Barnwell, i appreciate the feed back, i did not intend to use SO as a service, i was attempting to see if this was possible. i have this `^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$` regex for a lat long pair separated by a comma, but my input is one lat, then a separate long. so i'm trying to find another way.

Comment: Attie, I appreciate the feedback. I would normally yes, but I was hoping i could just put the regex in the pattern="regex" part of my form, so that I can easily utilize angular 2's form validator, instead of handling the data and then sending the status back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very pretty, you can try this one for the latitude

**-85.05112878 < *lat* < 85.05112878**

`^(?:-?85\.0(?:000000\d*|0{1,5}(?:[1-9]\d*)?|[1-4]\d*|5(?:0\d*)?|5(?:1(?:0\d*)?)?|511(?:[0-1]\d*)?|5112(?:[0-7]\d*)?|51128(?:[0-6]\d*)?|511287[0-8]?)?0*|(?:-[1-9]|-?[1-7]\d|-?8[0-4]|\d)\.\d+)$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      -? 85
      \.0
      (?:
           000000 \d* 
        |  0{1,5} (?: [1-9] \d* )?
        |  [1-4] \d* 
        |  5 (?: 0 \d* )?
        |  5 (?: 1 (?: 0 \d* )? )?
        |  511 (?: [0-1] \d* )? 
        |  5112 (?: [0-7] \d* )? 
        |  51128 (?: [0-6] \d* )?
        |  511287 [0-8]?     
      )?
      0*
   |  
      (?:
           - [1-9] 
        |  -? [1-7] \d 
        |  -? 8 [0-4] 
        |  \d 
      )
      \. \d+ 
 )
 $
```

And this for the longitude

**-180.0 < *long* < 180.0**

`^(?:-?180\.0+|(?:-[1-9]|-?[1-9]\d|-?1[0-7]\d|\d)\.\d+)$`

Expanded

```
 ^     
 (?:
      -? 180 \. 0+
   |  
      (?:
           - [1-9] 
        |  -? [1-9] \d 
        |  -? 1 [0-7] \d 
        |  \d 
      )
      \. \d+ 
 )
 $
```

---

***edit***

This is the same as above except it matches partial (valid) forms like

> *54
>
>   54.
>
>   54.1
>
>   etc ...*

**lat**

`^(?:-?85(?:\.(?:0(?:000000\d*|0{1,5}(?:[1-9]\d*)?|[1-4]\d*|5(?:0\d*)?|5(?:1(?:0\d*)?)?|511(?:[0-1]\d*)?|5112(?:[0-7]\d*)?|51128(?:[0-6]\d*)?|511287[0-8]?)?)?0*)?|(?:-[1-9]|-?[1-7]\d|-?8[0-4]|\d)(?:\.\d*)?)$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      -? 85
      (?:
           \.
           (?:
               0
               (?:
                    000000 \d* 
                 |  0{1,5} (?: [1-9] \d* )?
                 |  [1-4] \d* 
                 |  5 (?: 0 \d* )?
                 |  5 (?: 1 (?: 0 \d* )? )?
                 |  511 (?: [0-1] \d* )? 
                 |  5112 (?: [0-7] \d* )? 
                 |  51128 (?: [0-6] \d* )?
                 |  511287 [0-8]?     
               )?
           )?
           0*
      )?
   |  
      (?:
           - [1-9] 
        |  -? [1-7] \d 
        |  -? 8 [0-4] 
        |  \d 
      )
      (?: \. \d* )?
 )
 $
```

**long**

`^(?:-?180(?:\.0*)?|(?:-[1-9]|-?[1-9]\d|-?1[0-7]\d|\d)(?:\.\d*)?)$`

Expanded

```
 ^     
 (?:
      -? 180 
      (?: \. 0* )?
   |  
      (?:
           - [1-9] 
        |  -? [1-9] \d 
        |  -? 1 [0-7] \d 
        |  \d 
      )
      (?: \. \d* )?
 )
 $
```

Comment: this is what i meant by using a hammer to drive a screw

Comment: @WillBarnwell - Actually this was software generated. There are more examples of that hammer, like this [175,000 word Dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt) regex which creates a full blown trie. Does it reinforce your notion that regex is a bad thing ? Or, should you be the gatekeeper of when to use it ?

Comment: I don't think I am exerting a personal bias when I say that bound checking using numeric comparison is a much more sensible solution than a regex. I love regular expressions and pattern matching, but I believe that could != should

Comment: sln, Thanks for the feedback. yes, this is long. but yes, it is a solution. again, thank you for taken the time to put this up. it's a temporary solution, I may end up just putting the logic on the backend to validate the range per Will Barnwell's suggestion.

Comment: sln, on a side note, 42 is a valid lat that is being flagged by this regex

Comment: @WillBarnwell - Floating point's in conditionals are notoriously inaccurate and should be avoided like the plague. Decimal to binary to decimal is a bad circle.

Comment: @FussinHussin - Fixed a minor bug. Also, added a partial (valid) form match. Like `42` `42.` `42.0` will match as well.